# Indexing ranges of columns of array when only the indexes of the ranges are given

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, range

I am looking for an efficient way of indexing the columns of a numpy array with several ranges, when only the indexes of the desired ranges are given.

For example, given the following array, and a range size `r_size=3`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(18).reshape((2,9))

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

This would mean that there are a total of 3 sets of ranges `[r0, r1, r2]` whose elements in the array are distributed as:

```
[[r0_00, r0_01, r0_02, r1_00, r1_01, r1_02, r2_00, r2_01, r2_02]
 [r0_10, r0_11, r0_12, r1_10, r1_11, r1_12, r2_10, r2_11, r2_12]]
```

So if I want to access the ranges `r0` and `r2`, then I would obtain:

```
arr    = np.arange(18).reshape((2,9))
r_size = 3
ranges = [0, 2]
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Line that index arr, with the variable ranges... Output:
# --------------------------------------------------------
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]])
```

The fastest way that I've found is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

arr    = np.arange(18).reshape((2,9))
r_size = 3
ranges = [0,2]

arr[:, list(chain(*[range(r_size*x,r_size*x+r_size) for x in ranges]))]

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]])
```

But I am not sure if it can be improved in terms of speed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by splitting the array up in `r_size` chunks:

```
>>> splits = np.split(arr, r_size, axis=1)
[array([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]), 
 array([[ 3,  4,  5],
        [12, 13, 14]]), 
 array([[ 6,  7,  8],
        [15, 16, 17]])]
```

Stack with [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and select the correct `ranges`:

```
>>> stack = np.stack(splits)[ranges]
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

And concatenate horizontally with [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) or [`np.concantenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) on `axis=1`:

```
>>> np.stack(stack)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]])
```

Overall this looks like:

```
>>> np.hstack(np.stack(np.split(arr, r_size, axis=1))[ranges])
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]])
```

---

Alternatively, you can work with [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#numpy.reshape)s exclusively which will be faster:

Initial reshape:

```
>>> arr.reshape(len(arr), -1, r_size)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

Indexing with `ranges`:

```
>>> arr.reshape(len(arr), -1, r_size)[:, ranges]
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

Then, reshaping back to the final form:

```
>>> arr.reshape(len(arr),  -1, r_size)[:, ranges].reshape(len(arr), -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It perfectly does the task but I am afraid that it may be slower than the proposed method at the end of the question: 

```%timeit np.hstack(np.stack(np.split(arr, r_size, axis=1))[ranges])``` gives:
```36.9 µs ± 278 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)```

Whereas:
```%timeit arr[:, list(chain(*[range(r_size*x,r_size*x+r_size) for x in ranges]))]```
gives:
```4.84 µs ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)```

Comment: I have provided an alternative solution with `np.reshape`

Comment: Yes :) It is faster. Thanks a lot!. It gives: ```4.41 µs ± 19.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)``` for ```%timeit arr.reshape(len(arr), r_size, -1)[:, ranges].reshape(len(arr), -1)```

Comment: Your edit is actually very important indeed. I generally tend to use tensors which dimensions are unique in my minimal examples. This way there's less chance of falling into this kind of trap!

Comment: I agree with you and I'm sorry about that. Nevertheless, the answer was already crystal clear :)

Comment: Fancy indexing (using a list of indices to access elements of an array) will always copy the data if I recall correctly and reshaping it back to the final form will force ```reshape``` to make a copy. This means the data will be copied twice which might give a worse performance if you are processing large arrays. I think you can circumvent the first copy (from using fancy indexing) by changing the shape and strides of the array directly.

Comment: Indeed you're right @Kevin. Do you know why the 2nd reshape requires a copy while the first doesn't?

Comment: @Ivan The second reshape is incompatible for in-place modification. Simply put, the strides are misaligned and the only way to get it back to C order is to copy the array. You can verify this by trying to set the shape manually like ```arr.shape = (2,6)```.

Answer (score 1):

You will inevitably need to copy the data to get the desired result in a contiguous array. Although to make it efficient I would suggest trying to minimize the number of times you copy the data. Any kind of reshaping operation can be expressed with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-as-strided).

Assume the original array contains 64-bit integers, then each element is 8 bytes arranged in some shape:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(18).reshape((2,9))
arr.shape, arr.strides
```

output:

```
((2, 9), (72, 8))
```

so each column skips 8 bytes and each row skips 72 bytes. `arr.reshape(len(arr), -1, r_size)` can be expressed as:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, (2,3,3), (72,24,8))
```

output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

And `arr.reshape(len(arr), -1, r_size)[:, ranges]` can be expressed as:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, (2,2,3), (72,24*2,8))
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

So far, we have only changes the metadata of the array which means that no data has been copied. This operation has a near-zero performance cost. But to get the final array you will need to copy the data somehow:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, (2,2,3), (72,24*2,8)).reshape(len(arr), -1)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]])
```

This is not a generalized solution, but it might give you some ideas nonetheless on how to optimize.

Unfortunately, my timings do not back these claims but it is intuitive still and worth testing for some larger arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's an interesting alternative.